# Sensor Reading keeps increasing even after closing app, Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have make this app which calculates Linear Acceleration of device of all dimension, combines it, and calculates net acceleration. Top five acceleration values are stored in Shared Preference key-value pairs.

The problem is when I close the app and reopen it, I find the values increased to a much higher level. I don't seem to catch the point in the code from where it is happening.

Please Help me out.

ShakoMeter.java (this is my main activity where all sensor data is collected and stored)

```
package com.example.shake_o_meter;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ShakeOMeter extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

    float ro(double ax2) {
          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
          return Float.valueOf(df.format(ax2));
        }

    SensorManager smngr;
    Sensor sen;
    TextView t,t3;
    double max=-1;
    double ax = 0,ay = 0,az = 0;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    ArrayList<Float> list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shake_ometer);
        t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);


        // Showing initial message
        TextView textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textview.setText("Get ready to Shake It!!");
        textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textview.setTextSize(30);
        textview.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setView(textview);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();

        //Getting Sensor Control
        smngr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sen = (Sensor) smngr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);

        //Obtaining SharedPreferance for storing key-value pairs of high scores.
        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.shake_ometer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        list = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ax = event.values[0];
        ay = event.values[1];
        az = event.values[2];
        double temp=Math.sqrt(ro(ax)*ro(ax)+ro(ay)*ro(ay)+ro(az)*ro(az));
        if(temp>=max){
            max=temp;
            t.setText(ro(max)+"");
            list.add(sharedPref.getFloat("1", 0));
            list.add(sharedPref.getFloat("2", 0));
            list.add(sharedPref.getFloat("3", 0));
            list.add(sharedPref.getFloat("4", 0));
            list.add(sharedPref.getFloat("5", 0));
            if(max>list.get(0)){
                list.remove(0);
                list.add((float) max);
                Collections.sort(list);
                editor.putFloat("1", list.get(0));
                editor.putFloat("2", list.get(1));
                editor.putFloat("3", list.get(2));
                editor.putFloat("4", list.get(3));
                editor.putFloat("5", list.get(4));
                editor.commit();
                System.out.println(sharedPref.getFloat("5", 0)+" "
                        +sharedPref.getFloat("4", 0)+" "
                        +sharedPref.getFloat("3", 0)+" "
                        +sharedPref.getFloat("2", 0)+" "
                        +sharedPref.getFloat("1", 0));
            }
        }
    }



    public void onClickReset(View view){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onClickTopFive(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TopFive.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        final ShakeOMeter sh = this;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
                 smngr.registerListener(sh, sen, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

            }
        },3000);


    }

     @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        smngr.unregisterListener(this);
      }

     protected void onStop(){
         super.onStop();
         smngr.unregisterListener(this);

     }

     public void onDestroy(){
         super.onDestroy();
         smngr.unregisterListener(this);
         finish();
     }

}
```

TopFive.java (This is a sub Activity where top five activities are displayed)

```
package com.example.shake_o_meter;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TopFive extends Activity {

    float ro(double ax2) {
          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
          return Float.valueOf(df.format(ax2));
        }

    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_five);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T1);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T2);
        TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T3);
        TextView t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T4);
        TextView t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T5);
        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        edit = sharedPref.edit();
        t1.setText(ro(sharedPref.getFloat("1", 0))+"");
        t2.setText(ro(sharedPref.getFloat("2", 0))+"");
        t3.setText(ro(sharedPref.getFloat("3", 0))+"");
        t4.setText(ro(sharedPref.getFloat("4", 0))+"");
        t5.setText(ro(sharedPref.getFloat("5", 0))+"");
    }

    public void onClickReset(View view){
        edit.putFloat("1", 0);edit.commit();
        edit.putFloat("2", 0);edit.commit();
        edit.putFloat("3", 0);edit.commit();
        edit.putFloat("4", 0);edit.commit();
        edit.putFloat("5", 0);edit.commit();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top_five, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't know what's causing your problem. But in either case I'd put Sensor listening to a Service.

Comment: so, do I need to create a service and attach it to the activity? would that solve my problem?

Comment: Only putting the same code to a service wouldn't solve your problem, because Android programming is always solving a long chain of problems ;-)